# Angular NgRx subscribing to state leads to undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I set up a basic NgRx example in Angular 17.

this is my app.config.ts where I register my reducer in my store

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideStore({ counterReducer} ), provideStoreDevtools({
    maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
    logOnly: !isDevMode(), // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    autoPause: true, // Pauses recording actions and state changes when the extension window is not open
    trace: false, //  If set to true, will include stack trace for every dispatched action, so you can see it in trace tab jumping directly to that part of code
    traceLimit: 75, // maximum stack trace frames to be stored (in case trace option was provided as true)
  }),]
};
```

app.state.ts

```
export interface AppState {
  value: number;
}
```

counter.reducer.ts

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { increment, decrement, reset } from './counter.actions';
import { AppState } from "./app.state";

export const initialState : AppState = {
  value: 0
};

export const counterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(increment, (state) => ({ ...state, value: state.value + 1 })),
  on(decrement, (state) => ({ ...state, value: state.value - 1 })),
  on(reset, () => initialState)
);

export const selectCounterValue = (state: AppState) => state.value;
```

my-counter.component.html: This is where I want to show my current value of my State. I am aware that I dont have to subscribe to the count when using async pipe. Just for debugging cases I want to print to console

```
<button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>

<div>Current Count: {{ (count$ | async ) }}</div>
```

my-counter.component.ts This where i want to subscribe to my AppState.value. Basically i want to print it out when the state changes.

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import {increment} from "../store/counter.actions";
import {AppState} from "../store/app.state";
import {state} from "@angular/animations";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {selectCounterValue} from "../store/counter.reducer";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-counter',
  templateUrl: './my-counter.component.html',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
})
export class MyCounterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  count$: Observable<number>;
  subscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.count$= store.select(selectCounterValue);
  }

  increment() {
    this.store.dispatch(increment());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.count$.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

counter.reducer.ts:

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { increment, decrement, reset } from './counter.actions';
import { AppState } from "./app.state";

export const initialState : AppState = {
  value: 0
};

export const counterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(increment, (state) => ({ ...state, value: state.value + 1 })),
  on(decrement, (state) => ({ ...state, value: state.value - 1 })),
  on(reset, () => initialState)
);

export const selectCounterValue = (state: AppState) => state.value;
```

As you can see my console.log of my callback value is undefined
[image: devtools1]

However the value in my store is updated correctly when clicking on my increment button
[image: devtools]

I tried showing my entire state like this:

```
this.count$= store.select(state => state);
```

Now I always got a value when clicking but I just want to get the value and not the complete state
[image: devtools]

What am I missing? I think the undefined has something to do with my select. Basically this is the example of https://ngrx.io/guide/store.

EDIT:
I found a workaround but i'm not sure why this is working.
Inside my app.config.ts when registering my store i had to give it a name like this:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideStore(), provideState({name: "game", reducer: scoreboardReducer}), provideStoreDevtools({
    maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
    logOnly: !isDevMode(), // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    autoPause: true, // Pauses recording actions and state changes when the extension window is not open
    trace: false, //  If set to true, will include stack trace for every dispatched action, so you can see it in trace tab jumping directly to that part of code
    traceLimit: 75, // maximum stack trace frames to be stored (in case trace option was provided as true)
  }),]
};
```

After that i did it like this in my component:

```
constructor(private store: Store<{ game: AppState}>) {
```

...
}

I checked my store via Redux Devtools and i got values with this approach. When I remove { game: AppState}> it doesn't work anymore and my store is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue might be related to how you are selecting the value from the store. To address this, consider utilizing the `createSelector` function provided by the NgRx library.
Additionally, if you aim to streamline the process and avoid manually creating selectors for individual pieces of state, you may find `createFeature` from NgRx beneficial.

You can take a look at the docs to see how they both works:
https://ngrx.io/api/store/createSelector
https://ngrx.io/api/store/createFeature

Comment: @Paddy did you try some of these functions?

Comment: I tried it out. Maybe i did something wrong but i came out with a working solution. I've added it to my initial question. Thank you anyway! :)